# Print triangle pattern using nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to make a "Pyramid" that would look so if the height someone would input was say `2`:

```
 *
***
```

or if someone would input a height of about `6` it would look like this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

I got down the code for the previous triangle:

```
n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
for x in range(1, n+1):
    for y in range(n, 0, -1):
        if y > x:
            print(" ", end = "")
        else:
            print("*", end = "")
    print("")
for x in range(1, n):
    for y in range(n):
        if y < x:
            print(" ", end = "")
        else:
            print("*", end = "")
    print("")
```

That prints the triangle

```
     *
    **  
   ***
  ****
 *****
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and ***3*** lines

```
>>> n = int(input("Enter a value for n: "))
Enter a value for n: 6
>>> for i in range(1,n*2,2):
...      print("{}{}".format(' '*(n-i/2-1),'*'*i))
... 
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Comment: Yes, but thus us not a nested loop. I am required to use a nested loop, sir.

Comment: @Sarah From your own words *I am not asking for you to do the work for me*. I have just shown the math that is needed. Try to get the idea and implement it. I have answered keeping the community at mind. Some one else may find this helpful. If you still feel that I need to write the complete code please ping back. I will gladly delete this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier

```
n = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
for x in range(1, n+1):
    print("*" * x)
for y in range(n-1, 0, -1):
    print("*" * y)
```